# How to setup more than two Kibana instances for a single es cluster

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, elastic-stack

As Kibana is the webUI for elasticsearch, it is better make it high availability. After reading the doc and make a demo, i can not find a way to set up two Kibana instances simultaneously for a single Elasticsearch cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some deep leaning about Kibana, i finally find that Kibana will store its data and configuration about dashboard and searches in the backend ES. This way Kibana is just like a proxy and ES serves as the DataBase for it.

So, the answer is yes. Kibana supports High Availability through ES.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the `server.port` value to another free port (**ie: something like 6602**) in your `kibana` yml since 5601 is the default. Hence you're pointing to the same ES instance and having two (one running on the default port and the other running on port 6602) `kibana` instances as well.